# Selecting an element inside of the hovered "li" tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a few `<li>` tags and I need to hide an element inside of the hovered `<li>`tag.
The following code is not working, please let me know how can I get it worked...

```
$(function(){
  $("#deals ul li").hover(function(){
     $(this:has(".transform")).hide();
  });
});
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`this` is a DOM element. You can't combine it with jQuery selectors or strings to try to find an element.  `$(this)` is a jQuery selection containing the element hovered.  You probably need to use [`find`](http://api.jquery.com/find) to get the element you want:

```
$(function(){
  $("#deals ul li").hover(function(){
     $(this).find(".transform")).hide();
  });
});
```

I think you may also want the [`mouseenter`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter) event, rather than `hover`, if you are only binding a handler for the time when the mouse hovers over the element, rather than when it leaves it too.

Answer (score 1):

Replace:

```
$(this:has(".transform")).hide();
```

With:

```
$(this).find(".transform")).hide();
```